# PHP MySQL: After entering password and username, after clicking the login button, there is no redirection to the desired page

Tags: php, mysql

So I have newspaper vendor system where there are two entities, the admin and vendor.
After both signing up into the system, they are redirected to the login form where they input their username and paasword. The problem I'm having is that i am not taken to the respective pages that both the admin and vendor are supposed to be taken after clicking the login button. Instead redirects me to the login form again.
Any leads would be appreciated.
Thank you.

This the login form

```
            <form class="user" action="loginserver.php" method="POST" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="login_username" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="login_password" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
        
                <button type="submit" name="login_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"> Login </button>
                <hr>
               
            </form>
```

logic code for the login form

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['vendor_id']= '$vendor_id';
$_SESSION['vendor_email']= '$vendor_email';
$_SESSION['login_username']= '$login_username';


$login_username="";
$login_password="";
$errors = array(); 

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'news');

if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    login();
}
// LOGIN USER
function login(){
    global $db, $login_username, $errors;
    $login_password="";

    $login_username= trim($_POST['login_username']);
    $login_password=trim($_POST['login_password']);
    function e($val){
    global $db;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($val));
}
// grab form values
    $login_username = e($_POST['login_username']);
    $login_password = e($_POST['login_password']);

// make sure form is filled properly
    if (empty($login_username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
}
if (empty($login_password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
}

// attempt login if no errors on form
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $login_password = md5($login_password);

$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE login_username='$login_username' AND login_password='$login_password' LIMIT 1";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
    // check if user is admin or client
    $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
    if ($logged_in_user['login_rank'] == 'admin') {

        $_SESSION['admin'] = $logged_in_user;
        $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
        
        header('location: paper.php');        
    }
    elseif ($logged_in_user['login_rank'] == 'vendor')
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT vendor.vendor_id from vendor inner join login on login.login_id= vendor.vendor_login_id  where login_username='$login_username'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if(is_array($row)) {
        $_SESSION["vendor_id"] = $row['vendor_id'];

        header('location: home1.php');
    }
    }
    //elseif ($logged_in_user['login_rank'] == 'schoolhead')
    //{

    //  $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT schoolhead.schoolhead_id from schoolhead inner join login on login.login_id= schoolhead.schoolhead_login_id where login_username='$login_username'");
     //   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    //     if(is_array($row)) {
    //    $_SESSION["schoolhead_id"] = $row[schoolhead_id];
    
        

    //  header('location: requestschool.php');
    //}
    //}

    //elseif ($logged_in_user['login_rank'] == 'manager')
    //{

    //  $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT childrenhomemanagers.manager_id from childrenhomemanagers inner join login on login.login_id= childrenhomemanagers.manager_login_id  where login_username='$login_username'");
    //    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    //     if(is_array($row)) {
     //   $_SESSION["manager_id"] = $row[manager_id];
    
        

    //  header('location: requestmanager.php');
    //}
    //}

}else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
}
```

}

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code as you just stated what is wrong but didn't show in what code.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer anything to this question as it does not contain enough reference.

If you want to redirect in PHP you can use this function

```
header('Location: /desiredpage');
```

Comment: This could be one solution but the thing that he is redirected to the login page again confuses me as it should be a simple mechanism to not show any auth pages after successful login.

Comment: Exactly, Im redirected to the same page(login page) instead of being directed to either the admin or vendor pages